# How to handle a code from a Textbox HubSection?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a TextBox inserted inside a DataTemplate of a HubSection. How do I manage the properties from code in c #?
I want to change the property "Visibility"

```
<TextBox x:Name="NumeroTre" Text="3" Height="207.5" Margin="114.326,-50,113.506,0" FontSize="173.333" HorizontalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Comment: Bind it. You *are* using MVVM, right?

Comment: No, do not use it, partly because I do not know what it is, do not know him. I started programming recently

Comment: A whole tutorial is beyond the scope of an answer, so I answered your specific question with a link to a MVVM tutorial. Once you get 20 rep, consider coming by the WPF chat room if you run into any problems that aren't SO question-worthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in a data template, so using the name is pretty much out of the question. You should be doing it the MVVM way anyways :)

So, bind it. `Visibility` is an enum, so if you want to bind to a `bool` you need a converter:

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding SomeBoolProp, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"/>
```

The converter is super simple:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConveter
{
    public object Convert (...)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed
    }

    public object ConvertBack(...)
    {
         return Binding.DoNothing; //Or you could do the backwards conversion if you want
    }
}
```

If you aren't familiar with MVVM (Model, View, View Model) consider reading the following article: [Use the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj883732.aspx)